# how to find out common app friends on twitter using iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

Is there any way to find out the friends who already installed my iOS app from twitter friends, i.e. filtering friends who installed the app or not. I did that before with facebook friends I used fql for that, so I want to know is there any similar way for twitter or if not then what is the way to find the friends who already installed my app from user's twitter friends ? I already manage to sign in and get user's twitter(api v1.1) friends IDs from my iOS, but don't know what to do further. Please suggest me something, Thanks.

Comment: I also have that problem. If you solve this problem suggest me the way. Currently "friend on twitter" feature use in Foursquare app.

Comment: prabhu or Hemail, have either of you made any progress with this attempt to find app users within your user's Twitter friends?